# Enviar arquivo utilizado @Ajax.BeginForm e XMLHttprequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmlhttprequest

Estou com a seguinte dúvida:

Eu estou fazendo um post com `@Ajax.BeginForm`, porém o mesmo não envia arquivo, então eu queria utilizar a [File Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications), a minha ideia era a seguinte

Eu faria o `post` por `@Ajax.BeginForm` assim:

```
     @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Cadastrar", "Item", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post",OnSuccess = "onSuccess"}, new { Id = "formItem" }))
{
  <div class="box-body" id="boxNovoProduto">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Tipo)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Titulo)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Titulo, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Titulo, "", new { @class = "text-danger", required = "required" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LinkVenda)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LinkVenda, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Descricao, new { @class = "form-control textarea textarea-fixed", })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger", required = "required" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <legend><i class="fa fa-image"></i> Selecione imagens</legend>
                            <input id="inputImagens" accept="image/*" name="input44[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading">
                            <div id="blocoErroImagem" class="help-block"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div><br />

                    @if (Model.VideoAtivo)
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <legend><i class="fa fa-file-video-o"></i> Adicione um vídeo</legend>
                                <input id="inputVideos" accept="video/*" name="input44[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading">
                                <div id="blocoErroVideo" class="help-block"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div><br />
                    }
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer" style="margin-top: 10PX;text-align: center">
                    <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg  pull-right">Publicar</button>
                </div>
            }
}
```

E então, no submit eu enviaria o arquivo para o mesmo método ,algo mais ou menos assim :

```
 document.getElementById('formItem').onsubmit = function (e) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/Unidade/Item/Cadastrar');
        xhr.send(formdata);
        return false;
    }
```

Na controller eu recebo o seguinte:
public ActionResult Cadastrar(ProdutoCreateModel produtoCreateModel)

E minha intenção é receber o arquivo da seguinte forma:

```
Request.Files[i]
```

Porem ao dar `xhr.send(formdata);` tenho erro `500`,e o `Request.Files` sempre esta vazio,  eu não sei se poderia fazer isso, e caso isso não seja possível aceito sugestões.

Se puder explicar um pouco sobre o funcionamento ficaria eternamente grato.

Eu tentei fazer o envio para outro controller, no `onsuccess` eu chamei uma função chamada `sendFile`, ate funciona mas não achei que ficou muito legal, se alguem tiver alguma ideia de como fazer isso.

Comment: Como está o seu form? Tem como você colocar o código dele?

Comment: Postei o form completo, eu estou o formdata ja contem os videos e e fotos.

Comment: posta a sua controller também e o detalhe do erro

Comment: tentei explicar melhor.